# Mutt - View All Mail from All Subscribed Folders

Tags: linux, email, fedora, email-client, mutt

I'm running into an issue that I feel should be relatively easy to resolve, however I find myself unable to do so. :)

I currently have mutt set up with my email server and all is well regarding connectivity (using IMAPS).

The issue I have is that my "view" is only the Inbox. What I would like is to have all mail,  from every folder I am subscribed to, to show up in my default view. I did subscribe to my IMAP folders and even toggled to make sure.

I have the following set in my .muttrc:

```
set imap_list_subscribed                                                    
set imap_check_subscribed
```

I thought that would do it, but evidentally it doesn't.

Is what I'm looking for possible? Any suggestions, solutions or direction would be appreciated. Thanks.